# Assign score to data based on amount of transactions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to implement a query for assigning a score to members but not able to do so.

Here in the below example, the count of members is 10, but I want the count to be dynamic and I have done that through

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [Member No])
FROM Table
```

**Table structure:**

```
MemberNo    nvarchar(255)
TransactionDate    datetime
SalesNumber    int
SalesAmount    money
DateCreated    datetime
```

In the example

```
Member 1  - 5 Transactions
Member 2  - 5 Transactions
Member 3  - 10 Transactions
Member 4  - 10 Transactions
Member 5  - 100 Transactions
Member 6  - 100 Transactions
Member 7  - 15 Transactions
Member 8  - 15 Transactions
Member 9  - 2 Transactions
Member 10 - 2 Transactions
```

I would expect to see:

```
Top 20 % =  Member 5 and Member 6. They will each get a Score = 5
Next 20 % = Member 7 and Member 8. They will each get a Score = 4
Next 20% = Member 3  and Member 4. They will each get a Score = 3
Next 20% = Member 1 and Member 2. They will get a Score = 2
Last 20% = Member 9 and Member 10. They will get a Score = 1
```

Comment: In your table, there is no `Transaction` column. In your example, you did not provide number of transaction during which period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a CTE and compute the quintile rankings for each member.  Apologies for so many subqueries but it was the cleanest way to bucket every member into a quintile.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [Member No] AS memberNo,
           COUNT (*) AS memberCount
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY [Member No]
)
SELECT CASE WHEN t.rank < 0.2 THEN "first quintile"
            WHEN t.rank >= 0.2 AND t.rank < 0.4 THEN "second quintile"
            WHEN t.rank >= 0.4 AND t.rank < 0.6 THEN "third quintile"
            WHEN t.rank >= 0.6 AND t.rank < 0.8 THEN "fourth quintile"
            ELSE "fifth quintile"
       END AS quartile,
       t.memberNo,
       t.memberCount
FROM
(
    SELECT t.memberNo,
           t.memberCount,
           CAST(t.rn AS FLOAT) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) AS FLOAT) AS rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT memberNo,
               memberCount,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY memberCount DESC) AS rn
        FROM cte
    ) t
) t
ORDER BY t.memberCount DESC
```

Comment: @Shivang I'm glad to help you.  The reason I didn't go with your original output exactly is because it won't look nice (or be readable) to have many members listed in a single row.  But other than this, I tried to follow your question.